# Pandas: Using Groupby to Filter multiple groupings of column values with Start/End times, and count the number of groups with consecutive date ranges

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Struggling with this one...

I have a large data frame containing three columns with groupings (A, B, C) and two columns for datetime ranges (StartTime, EndTime), and a final column of values called Blocks.

I need to group the three cols: A, B, C -> and Count the number of "cycles" where the StartTime of the next row is within 1 day of the current rows StartTime.

-> So after grouping A-B-C; if we have two Blocks, one Ending on 7/19/23 and another Starting on 7/20/23, then we count this as 1 "cycle" in the output (I'm trying to filter out the match so I can later just count the values)

Attempt:

```
    df.sort_values(by=['A', 'B', 'C', 'StartTime'], inplace=True)

    df['DaysBetween'] = ( df['EndTime'] - df['StartTime'] ).dt.days

    mask =  ( 
            (df['EndTime'] != df['StartTime'].shift(-1) + pd.Timedelta(days=1)) & \
            (df['A'] == df['A'].shift(-1)) & \
            (df['B'] == df['B'].shift(-1)) & \
            (df['C'] == df['C'].shift(-1))
            )

    filter_df = sb[mask] # Filtering out the matching Blocks to later count the number of cycles
    filter_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    cycle_count = filter_df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'])['Blocks'].nunique().reset_index(name="CountCycles")
```

This kind of works but I'm losing rows where only one Block exists, and can't figure out how to keep them.

Comment: please provide an example of the dataframe.

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'Date': ['2010-01-01', '2010-02-01', '2010-03-01', '2010-04-01', '2010-05-01', '2010-06-01'],
    'HDD': [3000, 2500, 2000, 1500, 1000, 500],
    'CDD': [0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# Extract Year and Month columns
df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.month_name()

# Pivot the DataFrame to get the desired format
pivot_df = df.pivot_table(index='Year', columns='Month', values=['HDD', 'CDD']).reset_index()

# Flatten the column names
pivot_df.columns = [' '.join(col).strip() for col in pivot_df.columns.values]

# Optionally, you can reset the index and rename the columns
pivot_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
pivot_df.rename(columns={'Year ': 'Year'}, inplace=True)

print(pivot_df)
```

Output:

```
   Year  CDD April  CDD February  CDD January  CDD June  CDD March  CDD May  \
0  2010       1500           500            0      2500       1000     2000   

   HDD April  HDD February  HDD January  HDD June  HDD March  HDD May  
0       1500          2500         3000       500       2000     1000
```